Counterexamples to show that "$p < q ⇒ t^{±}(p) < t^{±}(q)$", and "$t^{±}$ are continuous" are not true
About this proposition
For a general spacetime $(M, g)$ the volume functions $t^{±}$
(a) $p < q ⇒ t^{±}(p) \le t^{±}(q)$,
(b) $t^{±}$ are upper/lower semicontinuous.
What counterexamples could I use to demonstrate that $t^{±}$ are not generally time functions ?(i.e., neither (a) holds with < instead of ≤ nor (b) with continuity)?
Some definitions:
volume function:
One can equip $M$ with a Borel probability measure $\mu$ that satisfies
$\mu(M)=1$
$\mu(U)>0$ for $\emptyset \neq U \subseteq M$ open
$\mu(\partial I^{±}(\rho))=0 \forall p \in M$
We define past (and future ) volume functions with respect to $\mu$ by setting
$t^{\pm}(p)=\mp \mu(I^{\pm}(p)), \forall p \in M$
time function: A continuous funciton $t:M \to \Bbb R$ is a time function if $p<q \implies t(p)<t(q)$
$p < q $  means that $p \le q$ and $p \neq q$
$p \le q $  means that there exists a future-directed causal curve from $p$ to $q$ or $p = q$
